# TCP traffic not working through Iperf tool in ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables, tcp, iperf

I am using system-A(interace name:**tun0**; IP: **192.168.3.1**) and system-B(interface 
 n
ame:**ss200**; **192.168.3.2**) which run on ubuntu. When I try sending traffic in TCP mode from A to B or vice versa, by using the correct Iperf commands it didnt seem to work.

So I tried this, I connected an ext.LAN cable from B to another Laptop(eth1,IP:10.0.0.3, gateway-10.0.0.1) and ran this commands in B-

1)**ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1 up**

2)**route add default gw 192.168.3.1**

3)**iptables -I INPUT -j eth1 -j ACCEPT**

4)**iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ss200 -j MASQUERADE**

After this I typed some commands at the Machine A-

1)**iptables -I INPUT -j tun0 -j ACCEPT**

After this I can send data in TCP form via IPerf command from laptop(**iperf -c 192.168.3.1 -i 1 -t -1**) to Machine A(**iperf -s -i 1 -t -1**). But when I want to send send traffic from A to B its not working.

I tried using above commands in reverse way but that too didn't work. The interfaces of A-tun0 and B-ss200 are created virtually and cannot be changed. Iperf in UDP is working fine, can someone please help